# Cities close to Stockholm to visit in a day

Tags: trains, sweden, day-trips, stockholm

Next summer I will be in Stockholm for 6 days , during one of these days I want to enjoy some city which is no more than 2-3 hours by train from Stockholm. Nice cities to visit? and what to see? I had thought Uppsala, Falun or ?

Comment: My favorite places outside Stockholm that are daytrip-worthy are Norrköping and Uppsala. I see those are mentioned already, so I'll only leave a comment. Enjoy!

Comment: your response is right! For nice I think the city where I can discover the power of the nature... the swedish ecosystem.. but also  a modern city!

Answer (score 4):

I think that this question will be closed as primary-opinion based, but still want to add that the best way to investigate a country is [avoiding the trourist traps](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/207/19) and select not first option you can find.

I suggest you the Eskilstuna city, there are a lot of museums there, zoo and park recreation zone you can walk in, and it is situated not very far from Stockholm: SJ (the largest train operator in Sweden) site is giving travel [time near the one hour](http://www.sj.se/travel/booktravel/timetable.form) from Stockholm.

Some inspirational photos here:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes - Eskilstuna is a nice option. The obvious ones near Stockholm (that some may consider tourist traps) are:

- Vaxholm (reachable by bus or boat)
- Mariefred (with the interesting Gripsholms Castle)
- Sigtuna (old city with several medieval church ruins)

Other options are:

- Uppsala (with a cathedral and old royal burial grounds)
- Strängnäs (nice old small city centre next to Mälaren with old church)
- Norrköping (if you like old industrial areas this is a must)
- Trosa (small coastal - not reachable by train though)
- Arboga (small and cozy by a canal)

Comment: Can you add some links for time tables and sightseeing for each city?

Comment: Yes! Will do when I have some more time.