# 'One laptop per child'- like organisations?

Tags: planning, work, around-the-world

One laptop per child (OLPC) is an organisation which brings laptops and technology to poor regions of this world and educates the people to use those tools.

As a computer scientist and passionate traveler, I seek a way to promote equal chances to everyone and support those in need. 
But right now I fall short of organisations who act like OLPC, so my question is if you know another, similar organisation?

Or any way to travel while working as a computer person. 
I know traveling and working as an English teacher is fairly straight forward, so I wondered if someone had any travel/work tips for me?

The last this world needs is another business app programmer..

Comment: Might be worth taking a look at http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/226/what-seasonal-work-can-fund-travel and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/website-resources-for-out-there-jobs-related-to-travel

Comment: Thanks Mark! I must have missed those questions. Nevertheless I think my question is relevant as it addresses whether there are other organisation similar to OLPC and specifically IT jobs which enable you to travel around the world. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have done some charity work with [Camara](http://camara.ie/), which has similar goals. Send 2nd hand computers to schools in Africa.

Comment: +1 for relevance to the question asked :)
Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Not to diminish your experience or the specific work that Camara does, but shipping 2nd hand computers (or anything 2nd hand) to developing countries is generally considered hurting the local economy as it inhibits the inception of a local industry in the particular product.

Answer (score 9):

I knew someone who worked for Geeks without Borders, which from my understanding does indeed help small businesses in the developing world set up IT and the like, so there may indeed be room there for a business apps programmer.

Comment: I tried searching for the Geeks without Borders but could only find a page describing their aims, no projects/jobs section? 
Could you maybe include a link? 

Also I am not actually a business app programmer ;)

Comment: Honestly, it was entirely word of mouth, so what I've got is what I've got. Sorry :\

Comment: no, thank you! I wasn't aware that something like Geeks without borders exists! so you did help me a lot. Plus the website i did find had some interesting listings of other organisations. :)

Answer (score 7):

A lot of roles like this come up on [EscapeTheCity](http://escapethecity.org/opportunities?zones=Professional,Volunteer).  I've removed 'Graduate' roles from the filter, but it should show both professional and volunteer roles for you.  Have seen some really useful and interesting ones there in the past, just not the ones I want...yet... ;)

To get an idea of what they do (and to see three of the awesome roles they've had):

http://vimeo.com/18922552

(It may sound like I'm affiliated; I'm not, I'm just really enthused by their model and wish there were more like them)

Comment: uhh nice! I can totally understand why you support them ;) 
Would be cool if they would expand the search engine a little though. Thanks for the share!

Answer (score 1):

Before they were gobbled up by IESC, I did two enjoyable stints with Geekcorps:

http://www.iesc.org/ict-and-applied-technologies.aspx

Their geographic reach is now limited, but if your technical area meets their needs and their geographic location meets your interest, perhaps you might be able to work something out.

Comment: Seam to have moved a bit further to the finance area, but thanks for sharing!