# Where can I find a New Orleans rental property for a guys weekend?

Tags: online-resources, accommodation, rental, new-orleans

We're looking to balance a proximity to the French Quarter and Bourbon street with a reasonable price and comfortable accommodations.  I've been searching VRBO, but the listings seem to emphasize the decor and charm of the property. I would prefer to focus on how sleeping arrangements and amenities.  Craigslist has listings as well, but many of those listings are warnings about scammers who advertise a fake rental property then take a deposit via check or credit card and vanish.  I'd prefer screened listings.

In our case we have four 40-somethings and we'd like to have separate beds, or couches.  Is there a site, or service that can find me a good short term rental for 4 days?

Comment: Have you tried http://www.airbnb.com

Comment: If you make that an answer I can accept it.  airbnb is what vrbo should be, and craigslist will never be.

Comment: The French Quarter has banned most short term rentals. Lots of hotel rooms up for grabs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [AirBnB](http://www.airbnb.com).

And in general you can look at [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/185/list-of-free-accomodation-resources?rq=1) to get many possible resources for accommodations.

Answer (score 2):

AirBnb is great, but you also can check HomeAway.com. One other thing to consider is that New Orleans tends to be low tech. So of you want to rent a place tou can find some great deals on Craigslist.

Answer (score 1):

I've always had luck with [VRBO.com](http://www.vrbo.com/).

I've used it over 20 times in the last 8 years and have had great success with each one. The searching on it can be a bit wonky if you don't know the neighborhoods in the area you're visiting. If I'm going someplace brand new to me, I try to spend a little time searching for maps that show (or at least describe) the names of areas/neighborhoods.

AirBnB is good too, but the last few times I've compared, there are still more properties for larger groups on VRBO. Hopefully, it will catch up soon because it is much easier to use.

Comment: OP already looked at VRBO and didn't like what he saw.