# Looking for a place for a 2 week trip to Calgary

Tags: budget, canada, accommodation, calgary

I want to visit Calgary next summer and I don't think a hotel room for 2 weeks is the best option, that sounds really expensive...  It is like a living-on-your-own trial that my parents are testing me with, so anywhere with a kitchen and my own private place would be great.  Do such places even exist? ...or do I need stay longer to have such an option?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Have you looked at airbnb, vrbo, homeaway?

Comment: Thanks :D I never knew such places existed... I'm not much of a travel person

Comment: Related/Possible Duplicate: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/185/is-there-a-list-of-free-accomodation-resources

Comment: I think the thing you might be looking for is a "long stay hotel" - they typically have a small kitchen in the room, and are typically priced for people staying weeks not days. Staybridge Suites, Home2, Homewood Suites and the like are the big hotel chain versions, independent ones exist too

Comment: Would a hostel work for you? You'd have to share a room, but the hostel I stayed in in Calgary had a great kitchen etc

Comment: Yeah a hostel would be great! Privacy would be nice though.

Answer (score 2):

So I spent about 5 days in Calgary last year, and stayed at [Wicked Hostel](http://www.wickedhostel.com/).

It's pretty close to the center of the city (I walked everywhere, despite it being -15C), and was a short bus ride from the Greyhound station. A nearby shuttle also takes you to/from the airport, where I met friends after my stay, before we headed into the Rockies.

It's full of fun, friendly people from all over the world.  Most people are out and about as they're sightseeing, so you can always get some quiet time if you want it, and then in the lounge there's still the option of socialising. They have events on as well.

Their kitchen is impressively full-featured, there's free wifi and free laundry too.

Note that you've not said where you're from, and one exception they have is you need to be out of state in origin.  If that doesn't work for you, you can check the other hostels in town on [hostelbookers.com](http://www.hostelbookers.com/) - many of them don't have that restriction.